# Vertical Sliding For Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-sliding

Is there any way to Vertical sliding for Fragments in Android? I mean something like `FragmentPagerAdapter` but in vertical mode. I need this to write a text viewer with vertical sliding pages, something like pdf readers.

Comment: Check this project https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager - supports paging both vertically and horizontally as well as changing between the two at runtime.

Comment: Thx mate , exactly what I needed :D

Comment: This is now deprecated and has build issues with the new appcompat libraries.